# How to add a picture onto JTabbedPane - on a null panel layout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, image, jtabbedpane

I want to implement a 200 * 200 picture onto my JTabbed Pane layout from the src folder.

My issue is that *nothing is showing*- no error no exception and no picture.

I dont think I have to declare the directory and set as a private as its already included in the src folder.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Example1 
        extends JFrame 


{
    private     JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private     JPanel      panel1;

    public Example1()
    {
        // NOTE: to reduce the amount of code in this example, it uses
        // panels with a NULL layout.  This is NOT suitable for
        // production code since it may not display correctly for
        // a look-and-feel.

        setTitle( "Program" );
        setSize( 800, 400 );
        setBackground( Color.gray );

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );

        // Create the tab pages
        createPage1();


        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Tab Page", panel1 );
        topPanel.add( tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    }

    public void createPage1()
    {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( null );

        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("test.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel (pic);
        panel1.add(label);
        label.setVisible (true);
        label.setBounds( 200, 200, 200, 400 );
}

// Main method to get things started
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Create an instance of the test application
        Example1 mainFrame  = new Example1();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );


    }
}
```

**If you want me to provide more info please ask for it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a null layout (and get ride of the setBounds()) on your panel.

The panel doesn't have a preferred size so Swing thinks there is nothing to paint.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIcon` doesn't display any error if an image cannot be found - make sure the image is located in the application directory of the application

Re using a `null` layout, from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager **if at all possible**.